# Implementing Google Cloud Message using appengine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement GCM, using appengine. I created the default appengine backend + GCM template and deployed it. 
I create a GCM registration id :

```
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);  //sender_id is my project number
```

Then i store this regID on appengine, using the default registration endpoint in the template. My broadcast receiver looks like this :

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Ayush", "Received");

        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="reach.project" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver
            android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
                <category android:name="reach.project" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <permission
        android:name="reach.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

</manifest>
```

The BroadCastReceiver and intent service are separate classes in my project. 
The appengine backend + GCM is a separate module.
During creation of this module :

> compile project(path: ':app2', configuration: 'android-endpoints')

This line got auto-appended to the build.gradle of main module.

> package com.example.mymodule.app2, is the path to my
>   MessagingEndpoint.

When I register the device, my broadcast receiver gets activated, but when I try sending a message from the appspot.com website, or from the api explorer, it doesnt receive anything. I can confirm that the messages are being dispatched, as shown by the logs in the backend.
Please help.

I was following this tutorial : 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/GcmEndpoints

Comment: Can you show more of your manifest? (the app's package name, the permissions)

Comment: Hello, I have edited my question, please have a look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the manifest, your app's package name is `reach.project`.

Therefore you should change

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

to

```
<uses-permission android:name="reach.project.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the above.
It works on my nexus 7, but does not work on my phone (4.0.4), I think its because of the Google account requirement. Any idea how to fix this ?